# AWS Apache in Public and Tomcat in Private Subnets

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am going for a typical web application deployment in AWS using public and private subnets in my custom VPC. I have the below setup done already...

1) Public subnet with an ec2 instance running apache web server.

2) Private subnet with an ec2 instance running tomcat app server.

3) AWS RDS mysql instance is created with it's publicly accessible flag set to NO and is available only within our VPC.

4) NAT instance which also doubles up as bastion host for private ec2 instances.

4) With all my NACL and Security Group Setting the below is working fine.

- I am able to ssh to private ec2 instance from by public nat ec2
  instance.

  Private ec2 instances are also able to connect to internet for
  updates.

  Private Tomcat server is able to access AWS RDS MySQL database.

  From my public web server I am able to send a curl HTTP POST
  request to private tomcat server and data is returned back.

Issue : We have our presentation layer deployed in Public Server within Apache and from the application when the same request is sent I am getting error in chrome -- net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. In IE 11 I am getting --XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Things I have tried so far. Enabled access origin headers and allowed necessary headers , have set loglevel to debug in apache but I don't see any thing there. It looks like the request itself is not reaching the app server , it's confusing when the curl post request is going through how come the apache request is not going through ??

Please provide inputs to move forward. Thanks

Public Route
**Destination  Target  Status  Propogated**
**45.0.0.0/16  local   Active  No** 
**0.0.0.0/0    IGW Active  No**

Private Route
**Destination  Target  Status  Propogated**
**45.0.0.0/16  local   Active  No** 
**0.0.0.0/0    NAT ENI Active  No**

Public NACL Inbound
**Rule# Type Protocol Port Range Source Allow/Deny**
**100   ALL  ALL      ALL  ALL   0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**
**110   HTTP* (8080)  TCP (6)    8080 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**

Public NACL Outbound
**Rule# Type Protocol Port Range Destination Allow/Deny**
**100   ALL  ALL      ALL  ALL   0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**
**110   HTTP* (8080)  TCP (6)    8080 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**

Private NACL Inbound
**Rule# Type Protocol Port Range Source Allow/Deny**
**100   ALL  ALL      ALL  ALL   0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**
**110   HTTP* (8080)  TCP (6)    8080 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**

Private NACL Outvbound
**Rule# Type Protocol Port Range Destination Allow/Deny**
**100   ALL  ALL      ALL  ALL   0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**
**110   HTTP* (8080)  TCP (6)    8080 0.0.0.0/0   ALLOW**

App Server SG-Inbound
**Type Protocol Port Range Source**
**HTTP* (8080) TCP (6) 8080 Web Server SG**
**HTTP* (8080) TCP (6) 8080 NAT Server SG**
**SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 NAT Server SG**

App Server SG-Outbound
**Type Protocol Port Range Destination**
**ALL ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0**

Web Server SG-Inbound
**Type Protocol Port Range Source**
**HTTP (80) TCP (6) 80 0.0.0.0/0**
**SSH (22) TCP (6) 22 My laptop IP**

Web Server SG-Outbound
**Type Protocol Port Range Destination**
**HTTP* (8080) TCP (6) 80 App Server SG**
**ALL ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0**

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to check your Security Group rules where HTTP and HTTPS added. After that check NACL inbound and outbound rules. Next Route table, because you have private and public subnet in your VPC.

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT occurs when HTTP or HTTP protocol off from Security Group or NACL.

Comment: I have opened up all the ports not sure what is going on. For testing purposes I have opened up more than required (I guess...) attaching the screenshots for my NACL , ROUTES and SG settings.

Comment: Details in my first post , don't have points to attach images

Comment: Continuing to debug the same issue, I feel there is no connectivity issues bcoz I can fire a curl post command form public webserver to private app server and it returns back with an expected response.                                                                                                    I was wondering if I need to look at configuration at the apache end like proxy virtual hosts etc. I don't think it is the proxy bcoz there is no domain involved here although the requests moves from public to private subnet...not sure about the correct direction to move ahead